# react-native-webview | 3Ds security not redirect a page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redirect, react-native-web

I'm using the AzeriCard payment gateway. when i try to do online transaction its after entering the card details it's not redirecting me to the 3Ds security page it's simply says **ACCESS DENIED** .. maybe it's problem with react-native-webview or what?
because from website it's working properly..
here's the code of webView

```
        <WebView
          ref={ ref => (this._webView = ref) }
          source={ {
            uri: paymentUrl, // payment uri is the redirectURL provided by AzeriCardGateway
          } }
          onNavigationStateChange={ (webViewData) => this.checkForBackRef(webViewData) }
          incognito={ true }
          style={ { marginTop: 0, opacity: this.state.opacity } }
        />
```